# VBA Syntax error in update statement, 3144

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm new to VBA, cant get a query to work

```
db.Execute "UPDATE t_inquiry " _
    & "SET [car rental contract printed?] = True " _
    & "WHERE [Customer_ID] = (SELECT [Gast_ID] FROM t_customer WHERE t_customer.[Mail 1] = '" & [rs]![Mail 1] & "')" _
    & "AND [car rental contract printed?] = [rs]![car rental contract printed?];"
```

theres something wrong in second line "where clause" if i remove that line then query works.

Does anyone have any idea please? thanks

Comment: You need to also concatenate the `[rs]![car rental contract printed?]` value.

Comment: u mean

'" & [rs]![car rental contract printed?] & "'

it was like that before, but didnt work, its a boolean value so i tried without and then it worked, as i mentioned, if i remove second line and keep only one "WHERE" clause [rs]![car rental contract printed?], then it works.

Comment: Do not double quote boolean values (they are like integers): `" & [rs]![car rental contract printed?] & ";"`

Comment: same error, I had already tried that, as I mentioned last condition worked only when i removed all quotes. Error appears only when I add this condition , WHERE [Customer_ID]...............

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271) -- see what you execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check spacing between string concatenated lines (for me, I usually place space at beginning to visibly see). Also, use the `IN` operator as opposed to equality `=` of the subquery:

```
db.Execute "UPDATE t_inquiry" _
    & " SET [car rental contract printed?] = True" _
    & " WHERE [Customer_ID] IN (SELECT [Gast_ID] FROM t_customer WHERE t_customer.[Mail 1] = '" & [rs]![Mail 1] & "')" _
    & " AND [car rental contract printed?] = " & [rs]![car rental contract printed?] & ";"
```

Comment: Strange, its producing the same error, but updating the value in the table, but why it is generating the same error after updating table?

Comment: You keep referring to "the same error" - I haven't seen you mention what the error message is anywhere? - edit - oh now I see it ! IN BIG TITLE

Comment: Put SQL into string -strSQL, add debug.print strSQL - show us that. Copy/paste text from debug into Query Window and run it there - better error message will appear.

Comment: while trying to solve this problem for 2 days, i had a lot of commented code and queries, one of the them was not commented and i didnt know that and that was actually producing the error not this one. It works now.
Thanks everyone.